# Read and write data from api

Tags: javascript, api

I need to read a value from a web page (dublek.ddns.net/awp/TemperatureMonitor/api.io) and display it on another web page every 5 seconds, and write the value back on toggle. Is it possible to do it, and what is the best way. Thank you.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but there's quite a bit of information missing in your question: Which language do you want to use? Should the site fetch the information on the user's side or on its own server? Does the remote server need authentication? What do you mean by "on toggle"?

Comment: Language doesn't matter, I just want the result. The site should fetch the information to its own server. I hope not, at least i think i disabled authentication on the device. I only want to change send back the value when i change it, not all the time. I am sorry for my ignorance, but I am doing only industrial programming, no web programming.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch() is a good way, but I checked this website and i couldn't find a way to request the response in JSON. The example below I used in a simple weather web app to practice fetch. As you can see we change the value of the url query (?="+inputValue) in the AddEventlistener method.

```js
//trigering Action Fetch api

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
fetch ('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+inputValue.value+'&appid=0f91ec65ce9099b9b43a35a9f89f6f26')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

  var nameValue = data['name'];
  var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
  var descValue = data['weather'][0]['description'];
```

Basically you just need to search on the response the attributes you want to acess, for this weather api the json response is:

```js
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},
"weather":[{"id":300,
"main":"Drizzle",
"description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],
"base":"stations",
"main":**{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15}**,
"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},
"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,
"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},
"id":2643743,**"name"**:"London","cod":200}
```

You can find this information on the documentation api page usually.

Comment: I am doing the api for a Siemens device, there is no documentation.